# Manipulating ADO.NET datatable rows and columns

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I have a datatable with columns a,b,c,d,e.

When column b is null, I want to set its value to the value of column a and then set all the other columns for that particular row to an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 System.Data.DataRow r = dt.Rows[0];
 if ( r["b"] == System.DbNull.Value )  //DbNull assumes the nulls are coming from DB.  If they are set to null via your code then you can use good old null instead.
 {
    r["b"] = r["a"];
    r["c"] = "";
    r["d"] = "";
 }
```